# Is there a key code with my Kawasaki

Tags: motorcycle, key, kawasaki, code

I hear that there is a key code for my 2006 Kawasaki Vulcan 900 LT that can be given to a dealer who can then cut a new key for my bike if ever necessary. Now it is. But where do I find the key code?? I am the 3rd owner but I have all the original paperwork when the bike was purchased new but they left the spot for the key code empty! So what do I do now??

Comment: With car dealerships, you take them the VIN and they can tell you what the key code is for the vehicle. I'm not sure if bike dealerships are the same, but you could try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, Kawasaki's have their key code stamped into the ignition switch.  Removal of the ignition switch is required in order to view the key code.

I believe with Kawasaki's you be required to have a pin in torx (also referred to as tamperless torx) driver in order to remove the ignition switch.

[image]

EDIT:
Where to look:

*On original key--if any.

*On Ignition housing

*Stamped on the back side of the Helmet lock-- Hint:  Removal is generally very easy

*Seat lock

*Fork lock housing

*Call dealer with VIN to obtain code.

Comment: I removed the ignition and there are four numbers on the back of it. Nothing else,only four numbers. Can i give these four numbers to a dealer or locksmith and get a key?

Comment: Those four numbers are what you want.  You can call you Kawasaki dealership to get a fresh key cut.

Answer (score 1):

The keycode on my Kawasaki Ninja is on the original keychain... its kindof like a mini-dogtag.

Comment: same on my Vulcan 900 classic 2006 had a little dog tag w- G- followed by 4 numbers